# How to declare accented variables in Python

Tags: python, character-encoding, unicode

I need to write **few basic scripts** for students in **Python**, like this one:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

mia_età = 31
print mia_età
```

But apparently I cannot use accented characters while declaring variables. Is there any way out?

*("mia_età" means "my_age" in Italian and I would like to avoid them to write grammar errors in their firts language while learning Python)*

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Python 1 and 2 only support ASCII alphanumeric characters and `_` in [identifiers](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#identifiers).

Python 3 supports all Unicode letters and certain marks in [identifiers](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#identifiers).

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
mia_età = 31
print(mia_età)
```

Identifiers are [normalized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_equivalence#Normal_forms) according to NFKC, so you can indifferently write U+0061 LATIN SMALL LETTER A followed by U+0301 COMBINING ACUTE ACCENT, or U+00E1 LATIN SMALL LETTER A WITH ACUTE.